# Looking for ideas on solid surface walls for a 36"x72"x36" shower

Tags: shower

Once upon a time 13 years ago we had custom 7' x 4' shower designed using Marblecraft that was professionally installed.  We had problems with the gelcoat discoloring and finally the walls separated from greenboard backing.  By the time the walls separated, the local Marblecraft was out of biz and so I was on my own.  I managed to fix it and that fix is still working...  but it was not fun.

So now we are remodeling a new house with the 36" x 72" shower and would like to use solid surface like Swanstone, etc and have it go from floor to ceiling.  However, everything I can find seems to be limited to a 60" width and I need 72" for no seams on the long wall.

Can anyone recommend or known of solid surface product that you can order that is 72+" wide?

Otherwise it's back to large format tiles and cement board, which means grout. (sigh)  Not the end of the world, but we do love the ease of cleaning our current shower.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Ordering a special size _should_ be no harder than ordering a custom countertop, even if it isn't in the usual catalogs ..